# Can I update Dartium to a newer version?

Tags: dartium

I am seeing that Dartium version is 46.xxx which is far behind Chromium which is currently 56.xxx. As what I see, v.46 is about 2 years old now.

Is it possible to combine Dart VM with a more recent version of Chromium or somehow get Dartium which has are more recent version?

What is the reason for the Dart developers to keep Dartium version so old?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR You probably can't (easily).

From [the phrasing of the instructions to build Dartium from source](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/wiki/Building-Dartium):

> These are instructions to check out and build a *modified version of*
>   *Chromium* that embeds the DartVM.

and further down

> A Chromium / Dartium checkout pulls code from ~90 repositories into a
>   single directory hierarchy.

I haven't delved into the source in a while, but it would require a team to maintain the changes every time Chromium is bumped, which is often and probably beyond the scope of what they want to do (since they didn't even bother doing a security audit of Datrium, also from link).

Furthermore, Dartium is not intended to be consumer-facing, but is *strictly* for developers, since Dart web apps are transpiled to JavaScript.

So, to update Chromium in Dartium, you'd need to port those changes yourself.